# How to register/add a command in dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am trying to use the functionality of dropwizard

http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#commands

I have written a class which extends from ConfiguredCommand and i want to add/register this to the dropwizard service/environment. I can't find out how to add/run the new command from dropwizard.

Answer (score 2):

`com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap` contains an addCommand method for adding `ConfiguredCommand`. You will get access to this object when you override initialize method in your service class, eg.

```
public void initialize (Bootstrap<T> configurationBootstrap) {
    configurationBootstrap.addCommand(yourCommand);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This helped. Do we need to initialize the commands in some other way of something like "DummyCommand d = new DummyCommand("name", "description")" would work??

Comment: I tried adding a command like this and tried to run it but i am getting an error like this
 "usage: java -jar project.jar [-h] [-v] {server} ...
java -jar  project.jar:  error:  invalid  choice:  'loadgen'  (choose  from 'server')

Comment: Look at these links and see if it helps you guys
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/19051ff1a80d7cdffa268d21f26a9e882ef7c82b/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/cli/ServerCommand.java

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/317f2e5cd4237fe5b94f5a525b0e3a3e4bc0667c/dropwizard-core/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/cli/ServerCommandTest.java